# Lipo battery with ESC and BLDC motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, lipo

I'm not sure if I can connect four brushless dc motors to my Lipo battery. I don't know how to calculate it. The brushless motor I have is the Turnigy L2210C-1200 brushless motor (150w) and the Lipo battery I have is the Turnigy 5000mAh 2S1P 20C Hardcase Pack (ROAR APPROVED). I should also probably say that the ESC I have is Turnigy Plush-32 30A (2~4S) Brushless Speed Controller w/BEC (Rev1.1.0).  Also how long can I use the brushless motors? I would like to make a flying car.

Comment: This question is more about the usage of batteries and model aircraft motors and systems, which isn't quite on-topic here. Maybe try [Drones and Model Aircraft](https://drones.stackexchange.com/).